# Formating String "2011-12-20 16:08:23" to Date object

Tags: java, simpledateformat

What pattern do I have to use for such String cos this one doesn't work:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
Format format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 5):

have you tired this?

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```